# Render plain html in Master Page web form

Tags: html, asp.net, webforms

I'm writing a web application in ASP.NET Web Forms. I have a Master Page and I will include some knockout templates inside. For some structural reasons I don't want to add that templates inside the Master Page code directly, so they will be in differents files.

**Structure.**

- 1. Masterpage.master
- 2. template1.template.html
- 3. template2.template.html
- 4. template3.template.html

I have done the same thing in MVC, but it was easy just rendering partials.

***Is there anyway to do the same thing with a helper class or something?***

I need that code in every page that includes that Master Page.

Comment: Why don't you add them into the master page? Or perhaps in a user control, which is roughly analogous to an MVC view partial?

Comment: I could create a custom control and add something like an attribute to specify the file path and then render what that file has in it with a stream.

Comment: Why not just move the markup into the control's .ascx?

Comment: Obviously I didn't think about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a user control (.ascx) file and move the required markup out of your HTML files and into the ASCX files. Then register the controls (at the page or web.config level) and use them in your master page.

See Also: [When do you need .ascx files and how would you use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217601/when-do-you-need-ascx-files-and-how-would-you-use-them)

Comment: Thanks I'm actually using it.