# How to avoid writing repeated content in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, kendo-grid

I want to avoid repeated html content in ASP.Net Web application. I have to implement a page which contain N number of Panels, each panel contains action buttons(Add, Edit & Delete) and a grid. The grid contains diff columns & data. like...

`<div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" Value="Add" />
      <input type="button" Value="Edit" />
      <input type="button" Value="Delete" /> 
    </div>
    <div>Kendo Grid</div>
 </div>`

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom controls (.ascx) that can be used on different webpages (and multiple times for page. You just put the reusable content in the .ascx, register the .ascx at the page or web.config level, then put it on the page. I'll borrow some code from [ScottGu's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/tip-trick-how-to-register-user-controls-and-custom-controls-in-web-config).

Create a control:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Footer.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebUserControl" %>
<div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" Value="Add" />
      <input type="button" Value="Edit" />
      <input type="button" Value="Delete" /> 
    </div>
    <div>Kendo Grid</div>
 </div>
```

If you want to register at the page level

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="scott" TagName="footer" Src="Controls/Footer.ascx" %>
```

If you want to register at the web.config level

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>   
    <pages>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="scottgu" src="~/Controls/Footer.ascx" tagName="footer"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Then you can embed the control on your page:

```
<scott:footer runat="server" />
```

See also: [when do you need .ascx files and how would you use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217601/when-do-you-need-ascx-files-and-how-would-you-use-them)

Answer (score 0):

You can add them programmatically or you can use a repeater control.  I would use a repeater control.